# $resource on $save() throws TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Resource factory:

```
.factory('WorkerRepository', function($resource){
    return $resource('workers/:id', {id:'@id'});
})
```

Controller:

```
.controller('ListController', function($scope, WorkerRepository){
    var workers = WorkerRepository.query(function(){
        $scope.workers = workers;
    });

    $scope.worker = {nameSurname: 'Peter', email: "test@gmail.com", phone: 600100200};

    $scope.add = function() {
        var worker = new WorkerRepository(this.worker);
        worker.$save();
    };
})
```

When `$scope.add` method is executed script throws an `TypeError: Object #<g> has no method 'push'` error. If I understand correctly `$resource`, `$save` method by default provides only `'save':   {method:'POST'},` so there is no `isArray: true`. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: I don't think you can reference $scope.worker with this.worker. I assume you are trying to save an empty worker, which might result in the type error. Even if it is empty, it should be an empty object, {}

Comment: `this.worker` returns plain object, I changed it to `$scope.worker` and get same error. After initialization `worker` var returns `q` object (which has method `$save()` in its prototype).

Comment: Make sure your POST response returns an object and not an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, error lied within my backend REST controller (thanks for the hint @Stewie!) - I didn't linked POST method to the action, so `$save()` method was invoking action responsible for `query()`, which indeed returns an array of objects.

Was:

```
query() -> GET  /workers -> return array of workers
save()  -> POST /workers -> return array of workers
```

After backend controller refactor:

```
query() -> GET  /workers -> return array of workers
save()  -> POST /workers -> return created worker
```